# Wayland on 14.04?

Tags: xorg, wayland

I'm getting insane amounts of tearing on 14.04, and was looking into when I stumbled on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182801/why-is-video-tearing-such-a-problem-in-linux). However, I'm not really sure what I'll be getting, or how to go about getting `Wayland`. There does not seem to be a `trusty` package for `Wayland` either.

Comment: Do you even know what Wayland is? And why would it solve your problems?

Comment: Not especially, but it seems like it's a Window Server that has a variety of features that XServer lacks. I'm down for learning more.

Comment: But what about compatibility? You would need a Window Manager/Desktop Environment which supports Wayland. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Well, the problem is massive screen tearing anytime I do anything in my browser or text editor. People seemed convinced that wayland was the way.

Comment: Then why don't you as a question about tearing here?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to install wayland on 14.04, not to say that it can't be done. But it looks like there isn't a package that's compatible with 14.04. A couple people have tried, including myself, using the instructions at the link below:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258304/xwayland-not-in-ubuntu